# Dynamically change highcharts by yearly,monthly an weekly base in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, highcharts

Can anybody guide me that how to change graph dynamically by clicking on dropdown menu list by yearly,monthly and weekly in codeigniter? i want to show the same values in these graph that i fetch from database but when user select yearly then take take the average of values and show on graph.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to try AJAX

Comment: can you refer any tutorial for this work?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Jquery plugin .
The plugin call datepicker.